# Jquery Modal Login Registration

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am working on a jquery modal login and registration. By default the modal window shows the login form. If I click on the show registration button, it switches to the registration form. The jqquery code supposed to execute on the current active (visible) form but it only seems to work with the default form (login). When I switch to the registration form, the code does not do anything and I can't figure out why. None of the jquery seems to work. It seems that once the jquery is loaded on page load, it won't let me redefine the plActiveForm variable which holds the ID of the current form. As you can see in the code, this variable is used throughout.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

I don't know if I'm making much sense, this is difficult to explain. My plugin is shown below:

```
// -----------------------------------------------
// JQUERY - FOR MODAL LOGIN + REGISTRATION FORM
// -----------------------------------------------
(function ($) {
$.fn.plMlogin = function (options) {

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // DEFAULTS AND OPTIONS
    // -----------------------------------------------
    var defaults = {
        plTooltip: true,
        plResetButton: true,
        plBubbleResponse: true
    };
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // SHOW MODAL WINDOW ON CLICK
    // -----------------------------------------------
    $('.pl-m-trigger').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // -> append container into body
        $('body').append('<div class="pl-m-container">');

        // -> load modal forms into container
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pl-module/public/modal-login-html.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            timeout: 10000, // 10 seconds
            success: function(html) {

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // -> LOAD FORMS INTO CONTAINER
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(".pl-m-container").html(html);

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // PROPERTIES
                // -----------------------------------------------
                var plMContainer = $('.pl-m-container');
                var plMWrap = $('.pl-m');
                var plMOverlay = $('.pl-m-overlay');
                var plMLoginFrm = $('#pl_frmMlogin');
                var plMRegFrm = $('#pl_frmMRegister');
                var plMLoading = $('.pl-loading');
                var plMCloseBtn = $('.pl-m-close');
                var plMShowRegBtn = $('#pl_showRegForm');
                var plMShowLoginBtn = $('#pl_showLoginForm');
                var plMLoginSubmitUrl = 'pl-module/public/login.php';
                var plMRegisterSubmitUrl = 'pl-module/public/register.php';
                var plActiveForm = plMLoginFrm;
                var plSubmitUrl = plMLoginSubmitUrl;

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // SHOW MODAL WINDOW AND DEFAULT FORM
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMWrap).fadeIn('fast');
                $(plMOverlay).fadeIn('fast');
                $(plActiveForm).fadeIn('fast');

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // CLOSE MODAL WINDOW ON BTN CLICK
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMCloseBtn).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(plMWrap).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $(plMOverlay).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                            $(plMContainer).remove();
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // CLOSE MODAL WINDOW ON OVERLAY CLICK
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMOverlay).click(function() {
                    $(plMWrap).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                            $(plMContainer).remove();
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // SWITCH TO REGISTRATION FORM
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMShowRegBtn).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    plResetForm();
                    $(plMLoginFrm).slideUp('fast', function() {
                        $(plMRegFrm).slideDown('fast', function(){
                            // set active form to registration
                            plActiveForm = plMRegFrm;
                            plSubmitUrl = plMRegisterSubmitUrl;
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // SWITCH TO LOGIN FORM
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMShowLoginBtn).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    plResetForm();
                    $(plMRegFrm).slideUp('fast', function() {
                        $(plMLoginFrm).slideDown('fast', function(){
                            // set active form to login
                            plActiveForm = plMLoginFrm;
                            plSubmitUrl = plMLoginSubmitUrl;
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // RESPONSE MESSAGES
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plResponse(plMsg, plShowHide) {
                    var plResponse = $('.pl-response', plActiveForm);
                    if (plShowHide === true) {
                        $(plResponse).fadeIn('slow').html(plMsg);
                    } else if (plShowHide === false) {
                        $(plResponse).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // RESET FORM BUTTON CLICK
                // -----------------------------------------------
                if (settings.plResetButton) {
                    var plResetBtn = $('.pl-reset-btn', plActiveForm);

                    $(plResetBtn).click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        plResetForm();
                    });
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // RESET FORM FUNCTION
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plResetForm() {
                    $('.pl-cust-response', plActiveForm).remove();
                    $('.pl-error', plActiveForm).removeClass('pl-error');
                    plResponse('', false);
                    plResetBtn.hide();
                    $(plActiveForm)[0].reset();
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // FORM VALIDATION
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plValidate() {
                    // remove custom errors if visible
                    $('.pl-cust-response', plActiveForm).remove();

                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // CHECK - EMPTY REQUIRED FIELDS
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    $(plActiveForm).find('.pl-required').each(function () {
                        var plEmptyCheck = $.trim($(this).val());
                        if (plEmptyCheck.length == 0) {
                            plResponse(PLLANG.MSG_03, true);
                            if (settings.plBubbleResponse) {
                                $(this).parent().append('<span class="pl-cust-response">' + PLLANG.MSG_04 + '</span>');
                                $('.pl-cust-response').fadeIn('slow');
                            }
                            $(this).addClass('pl-error');
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass('pl-error');
                        }
                    });

                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // IF ERROR(S) FOUND
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    var $errors = $('.pl-error', plActiveForm);
                    if ($errors.length > 0) {
                        if (settings.plResetButton) {
                            plResetBtn.show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        plResponse('', false);
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // FORM SUBMIT
                // -----------------------------------------------
                plActiveForm.submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // if validation is ok
                    if (plValidate() === true) {
                        var plFormData = $(this).serialize();
                        plAjaxSubmit(plFormData);
                        $(plMLoading).show();
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // AJAX SUBMIT FUNCTION
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plAjaxSubmit(plFormData) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: plSubmitUrl,
                        data: plFormData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        timeout: 20000,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                if (value.error == true) {
                                    // hide loading image
                                    $(plMLoading).hide();

                                    plResponse(value.msg, true);

                                    // show reset button
                                    if (settings.plResetButton) {
                                        plResetBtn.show();
                                    }
                                } else if (value.error == false) {
                                    // reset form
                                    plResetForm();

                                    // hide loading image
                                    $(plMLoading).hide();

                                    // display success message
                                    plResponse(value.msg, true);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            plResponse(PLLANG.MSG_06, true);

                            // hide loading image
                            $(plMLoading).hide();
                        },
                        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, status) {
                            // hide loading image
                            $(plMLoading).hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);

// -----------------------------------------------
// INSTANTIATE MODAL LOGIN
// -----------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pl-m').plMlogin({
        plTooltip : true,
        plResetButton : true,
        plBubbleResponse : true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `.click(function(e){...})` method, use the [`.on('click', function(e){...})`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. The `.on()` method works on dynamically modified HTML, while the other event methods only work on the original HTML.

---

Also, just a suggestion, you can declare multiple variables like this instead:

```
            var plMContainer = $('.pl-m-container'),
                plMWrap = $('.pl-m'),
                plMOverlay = $('.pl-m-overlay'),
                plMLoginFrm = $('#pl_frmMlogin'),
                plMRegFrm = $('#pl_frmMRegister'),
                plMLoading = $('.pl-loading'),
                plMCloseBtn = $('.pl-m-close'),
                plMShowRegBtn = $('#pl_showRegForm'),
                plMShowLoginBtn = $('#pl_showLoginForm'),
                plMLoginSubmitUrl = 'pl-module/public/login.php',
                plMRegisterSubmitUrl = 'pl-module/public/register.php',
                plActiveForm = plMLoginFrm,
                plSubmitUrl = plMLoginSubmitUrl;
```

I'm not sure if it's better performance-wise but it looks more organized in my opinion.

Comment: Nop.That seems to not help either. I also tried using live().